# Python create path with file

Tags: python, file-io

Is there a way to create a file and automatically create its path?

for example:

```
with open("./path/to/file/data.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("hello")
```

I want it to create the path `./path/to/file` and then create the file `data.txt` and open it.
instead it will give the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './path/to/file/data.txt'
```

I don't want to have to manually create the path one folder at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os

os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(fullPath))
```

Answer (score 0):

To know or get a file location or path, you first of all create a file module, on creating the file name module, python already knows its path. To create a module name use

```
               import os
             
               os.mkdir('data.txt')
```

You can use the code below to know or display the file module path displayed in your output shell.

```
               import os

               result = os.getcwd()
```

You can then further to create the file using

```
               with open('data2.txt', 'w') as f:
               f.write('You are good')
```

I added 2 to the file name i.e 'data2.txt' because python does not permit same name for file module as file name in the same directory.